# Raising event on ActiveX variable change

Tags: vb.net, activex

I am writing a visual basic program that interfaces with another program through an ActiveX COM library. Basically, I want to raise an event whenever a variable in the activex COM library changes from 0 to 1 and increment a serial number in my program.

To restate, there is a variable [activex.isMarking] that I get from the ActiveX library and most of the time is 0. When [activex.isMarking] changes to 1, I want to raise an event to wait until [activex.isMarking] goes back to 0, then += 1 to a serial number. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Are you able to make modifications to the COM library?  I assume, based on your question, that it doesn't currently have such an event already.

Comment: No, it doesn't have the event already and I can't modify the COM library

Comment: And the value of that property can be changed by code that is also outside of your control?

Comment: Yes, I do not have control over the code that determines what value [activex.isMarking] has.

Comment: In that case, your options are not very good.  You could poll the value with a timer, but you may miss some changes, and depending on the interval, it could be too inefficient.  Alternatively, you could spoof the system by creating your own COM library with an identical COM interface and have it be a simple pass-through wrapper around the original COM library, but that could be quite involved, especially if the library is complex.  Other than that, no other options come to mind, but maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Comment: The timer could work, since I have a rough Idea of how long of a period exists in between a change (its on the order of 10s of seconds so it is not that fast changing).